# Chat, conversation, messaging - CoreData model

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, data-modeling

Before you mark a question as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934247/design-for-a-chat-app-using-core-data) please read a description. I don't need to continue discussion there in the comment.

So I want to create `CoreData` model for messaging app. Like said in this topic did i mentioned - i've had three entities:

1. `User` entity define a author of message and participant in a conversation.
2. `Message` entity define every text sending with app.
3. `Conversation` entity defines conversation beetwen users using messages.

OK so my data model is like:
[image: Data model]

But everything is connected to each other here. The only difference between mentioned answer and my solution is that **`User` and a `Message` are connected using one-to-many relationship**. I think i need that, becouse without that it's impossible to know who wrote what in a conversation.

But as far as i know data model when everything is connected to each other have no sense.

So the key goals here is:

1. In conversation screen i want to know who wrote what
2. In one conversation can participate at least two users
3. The message is text-only
4. User have to be able to list all his conversations.

That's it.

Please validate the current solution and feel free to criticize.

Comment: consider using a fetchedProperty or a normal property containing the objectID for the author thus making the author relationship unnecessary. The same could be done for participants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no real need for the many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Conversation`.

If a user like to get all of its conversations he could use this fetch request:

```
User* user = //get some user you like conversations for
NSFetchRequest* r = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Conversation"];
r.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY messages.author = %@",user];
```

In the same fashion you could get all users of a given conversation.

You could model this as a fetched property on each of these entities (`User` and `Conversation`).

**You should really consider changing the `chat` relationship to `messages`**