# CoreData circular reference

Tags: ios, core-data

I modelled my Core Data objects according to the app's logic like this:
[image]

I know that in DB modelling it is recommended to avoid circular references, but since everybody is advising that you should forget SQL when working with Core Data, is it ok to have this kind of circular reference? If not, would replacing one of the relations (e.g. between D and E) with a fetched property be a solution? Thank you in advance!

Comment: very similar to [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529175/chat-conversation-messaging-coredata-model/22530029#22530029)

Comment: Not sure it's a problem, but I do wonder whether some of the relationships could be simplified with some subclassing. Make an abstract class that encompasses several of ABCDE, and rather than two relationships pointing to two distinct types, you can collapse them into a single relationship set of superclass objects that you can sort by type.  But that's just speculation knowing nothing of ABCDE here.